# Who's calling my gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am writing a gem and in my gem I need to know the location (absolute) of the file calling my gem. How can I get that information? I have tried using things related to `caller` but it doesn't give the the location, only the caller method name.

Comment: What do you mean? `caller` does show full file path.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev how? when I try `puts caller` it says `test.rb:3:in '<main>'`

Comment: Works in IRB, at least. http://pastie.org/10384305 I'll try with a gem tomorrow.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev OK thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`caller` is archaic. Use `caller_locatons`.

```
caller_locations(0, 1).first.absolute_path
```

If this is not what you want, change the first argument of `caller_locations` to `1`, etc.

Comment: Nice one, didn't know about it.

Comment: This puts the path of my gem not the caller. I don't know why

Comment: Then try changing the first parameter like `caller_locations(1, 1)` etc.

Comment: @sawa OK! That worked for me! The only thing I did differently is that I got an error `undefined method absolute_path for array<#jaoihgoiawhioawhf>` or something so I did `caller_locations(1,1)[0].absolute_path` also, it seemed that `caller_locations(0,1)` is the path of the gem. Could you please add this info to your answer?

Comment: @sawa could you also add that because `caller_locations(x,y).absolute_path` doesn't work because  `caller_locations(x,y)` is an array so it must be `caller_locations(x,y)[0].absolute_path`

Comment: I had already edited to add `first`, which is better than `[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
# requieree.rb
puts File.absolute_path(caller.first.split(':').first)
```

---

```
#requierer.rb
require_relative 'requieree'
```

---

```
ruby requierer.rb # => /home/__user__/Desktop/requierer.rb
```